# How to create a custom dashlets?

Tags: dashboard

I want to create a custom dashlet but I don't know how to do that.Please guide me to build a new dashlet. Any github reference or any source.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Start with `civix generate:page`. Optionally assign some smarty variables in run() in the autogenerated php class and edit the autogenerated .tpl with your html.

Then you need to insert an entry in civicrm_dashboard that links the url you chose in generate:page. See the function addGettingStartedDashlet() in CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourSeven.php, just note the columns have changed slightly if you're on a later version.

Comment: Will you provide a snippet?

Comment: Take a look at CRM/Dashlet/Page/GettingStarted.php. Did you try using `civix generate:page`? Try it first and then if you have a specific part that isn't working you can ask about that.

Comment: I created an extension using civix tool. But I don't have any idea about the dashlet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example dashlet with a search: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.quicksearchdashlet

Comment: I tried downloading the extension using ./cv ext:download org.civicoop.quicksearchdashlet but it does not show up in the list