# How do I display user statistics/analytics on their dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, user-dashboard

I'm using civicrm and I'm wondering how I can better customize the home dashboard. We have people that are going to be doing walklists and interviewing them. How can I make it so that when they log in, they can see how many people they interviewed so far? Keep in mind that it is specific to all volunteers so ideally, I'd like it if I could setup a global view where they can see how many contacts they have interviewed.

I hope there's a straightforward way to do it. I'm open to using SQL or anything to get it to work. Is there a way to add custom HTML to the dashboard as well? I want the UX/UI to be very simple for volunteers so I'd like to have custom buttons to tell them to 'Start Interviewing' in their walklists, rather than have to go through the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using the campaign report (which can be made into a dashlet by checking the Available For Dashboard checkbox when you save - see https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/menu-dashboard-and-dashlets/#dashlets), then you could either use https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_dashboard/ to put something custom into the /civicrm/user page, or make your own dashlet to be available at /civicrm/dashboard (see e.g. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/28877/181)

Comment: That new dashlet stackoverflow helped alot! thanks! (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28875/how-to-create-a-custom-dashlets/28877#28877)